# jQuery UI Datepicker for a Html.TextBox control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to show the jQuery UI Datepicker plug in for `Html.TextBox`, how can I do this?

jQuery Code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">
     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" style = "width:150px"/></p>
</div>
```

The above code gives me a text box control in my MVC view where I can click on the control and it pops up a calendar control, it works well, but what I want is to reproduce the same behavior for a `Html.Textbox` I am using later in the code, like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Date", "", new { style = "width:150px"})%>
```

How can I get the jQuery UI Datepicker plugin to work in the above line of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `class="datepicker"` to your `htmlAttributes`

```
  <script>
 $(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
 });
 </script>

 <div class="demo">
     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" style = "width:150px"/></p>
 </div>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Date", "", new { style = "width:150px", @class = "datepicker"})%>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 identical ids on the same page.

Comment: I tried this before. It did not work. Now I commented the first text box <input type="textbox".....> and then Html.TextBox started working. Is it because datepicker can be used by only one at a time...?

Comment: @Ayman Safadi do you realy think I belive a down vote for that?

Comment: @ZVenue use class instead of id, you can have multiple elements with same class name.

Comment: How can I make the Html.TextBox take only input from the calendar and not typing?

Comment: Yes. I assume you meant "deserve". Not only does your solution not work, but you also could have left @ZVenue (who may be a beginner) with the idea that it's OK to have 2 identical ids on the same page. Nothing personal, I just want to encourage you to offer better answers.